# Get string inbetween text Python

Tags: python, string, variables, python-2.7

If I have:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2014:03:36:46 +0100] "POST /info HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "http://website.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36" "name=josh&zipcode=12345"
```

How would I be able to extract "josh" and "12345" to their own variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the string by spaces, take the last element, strip quotes and use [urlparse.parse_qsl()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl) to parse query parameters:

```
>>> from urlparse import parse_qsl
>>> s = '127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2014:03:36:46 +0100] "POST /info HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "http://website.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36" "name=josh&zipcode=12345"'
>>> params = parse_qsl(s.split()[-1].strip('"'))
>>> params
[('name', 'josh'), ('zipcode', '12345')]
```

Then, to assign variables to the parameter values, you can unzip `params`:

```
>>> name, zipcode = zip(*params)[1]
>>> name
'josh'
>>> zipcode
'12345'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this following code, assuming all of the following strings will be in the same format:

```
>>> info = '127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2014:03:36:46 +0100] "POST /info HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "http://website.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36" "name=josh&zipcode=12345"'
>>> name = info.split()[-1].split('&')[0].split('=')[1]
>>> code = info.split()[-1].split('&')[1].split('=')[1]
>>> name
'josh'
>>> code
'12345'
```

The first `.split()` is to get the entire string as a list.

The `[-1]` is to get the last item in the list.

The `.split('&')` is to split the last sequence by the `'&'`.

The `[0]` or `[1]` is to specify which value we want to obtain, the name or the code.

The `split('=')` is to split each value by the equals sign, so that we can obtain the name or the code as one value.

The last `[1]` is to get the last value, basically to exclude the `'name'` or `'zipcode'`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the split function...

```
o = "name=josh&zipcode=12345"

a = o.split('&') # ['name=josh', 'zip=12345']
d = dict(s.split('=') for s in a)
```

would give you a nice dictionary of key value pairs :)

```
{'name':'josh','zip':12345}
```

or you could use something else depending on what you need... http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

```
string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])
    Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.
```